# CardStackView.Rewind() is not functioning in Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-cardview, mobile-application

I am using this [cardStackView](https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView) to display some set of pictures to swipe(Left,Right,Top). onClick() of rewind button I am trying to rewind the previous card by calling this rewind() method below. which is working great!!

```
public void rewind()
{
        manager.setRewindAnimationSetting(new RewindAnimationSetting.Builder()
                .setDirection(Direction.Right)
                .setDuration(Duration.Normal.duration)
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
                .build());
        cardStackView.rewind();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Executed Rewind", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But now I want to call this method on a condition(i.e Swipe limit reached per day), which is executing successfully but card is not getting rewind.

```
public void SwipePerformed()
{
    if(SwipeFragment.user_premium)
    {
        DoSomeAction();
    }
    else
    {
        if (user_SwipeCount >= SwipeLimit)
        {
            rewind(); //Rewind to previous card, limit reached.
            getPremiumWindowDisplay();//Display Get Premium View.           
        }
        else
        {
            PerformSomeAction();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, the rewind method is getting called and executed but card is not getting rewind.
please help me with this. I am not getting what is the issue..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another instance of manager check

> Blockquote

```
    rewindButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            RewindAnimationSetting settings = new RewindAnimationSetting.Builder()
                    .setDirection(Direction.Bottom)
                    .setDuration(Duration.Normal.duration)
                    .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
                    .build();

            CardStackLayoutManager cardStackLayoutManager2 = new CardStackLayoutManager(mContext);
            cardStackLayoutManager2.setRewindAnimationSetting(settings);
            cardStackView.setLayoutManager(cardStackLayoutManager2);
            cardStackView.rewind();
        }
    });
```

> Blockquote